# How can I get id when searching by name in C# lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity

My task is simply to get ManufacturerId, searching by manufacturer (name), from database using Entity Framework.

```
 public int GetManufacturerId(string manufacturer)
    {
        aEnteties = new PGDEnteties();
        return aEnteties.MedicineManufacturers.(x => x.ManufacturerId(x.ManufacturerName == manufacturer));
    }
```

This code isn't working :(

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax doesn't look right, try:

```
var m = aEnteties.MedicineManufacturers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ManufacturerName == manufacturer);
return m == null ? -1 : m.ManufacturerId;
```

I've returned -1 if we don't find a match but you might want to do something else.

This link gives more LINQ query examples: [MSDN Queries in Linq to Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399367(v=vs.100).aspx)